Reporting Hierarchical Regression Results in Abstract
I did a hierarchical regression test in a social science study looking at how two variables (A and B) and their interaction term can predict variable C. My mentor told me to write in the abstract that "Our findings confirmed that both A and B could independently predict C (stats)."
I'm not sure what values are generally included in the (stats) part of abstracts. The same goes for my moderation analysis - when I added a new moderator, I was not sure what stats to include in my abstract as well.

This very much depends on the outlet. Check the abstracts of articles published in journals you consider, especially those doing something similar as you.

I assume that by hierarchical regression (HR), you mean this and not mixed models. As another commenter noted, there probably exist different conventions in different sciences for this. However, I think that what holds for linear regression holds just as well for HR, and whatever model "blocks" or "steps" need their changes listed too.
Some things that I would deem essential:

Coefficients and their normal inferential values (slopes, confidence intervals, etc.).
All omnibus model-based output like $F$, adjusted $R^2$, and residual standard error values for each block/model.
All block change estimates like $\Delta F$ and $\Delta R^2$ values for each subsequent model/block.
At least some indication that model assumptions are investigated with some basic checks and how the model departs from those assumptions (and if they can be safely ignored if so). Most importantly are that your model has approximate linearity and independence of errors.
Visualization. I don't think I've seen a single HR that has attempted to visualize anything they've produced, which is bonkers considering how poorly these can be fit without looking at how the model fits the data.

The link above gives two examples which provide some of this at the end, but I find them too lacking on details. This one from from an article in my field does a better job of putting a lot of what I said in there:

As a side note, I will say that I'm not as much a fan of HR, but I think that largely stems from how often it is mis-used (namely because of $p$ value criticism of the blocks that are standard).
If your concern is purely the abstract alone, then you can't really sneak in everything here. So probably given the model comparisons are the most important thing, I would at least add the $\Delta$ changes in models and the inferential estimates related to each block's test. From the same linked article from my field, they had this more general summary:

You can always check out articles in your field's journals to see how they report them by convention.
